# KGDB remote debugging error

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, gdb, kernel

I am trying to debug the Linux kernel using kgdb. I am using qemu as target machine. Ubuntu 12.04 is my host OS. I tried this command

```
cyborg@skynet:~$ qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel zImage -initrd rootfs.img.gz -append "root=/dev/ram rdinit=/bin/sh kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdbwait"
```

It will boot and wait displaying

> **kgdb: Waiting for connection from remote gdb**

And when I try to debug using gdb on linux host using the commands

```
cyborg@skynet: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gdb vmlinux
```

(gdb): set remotebaud 115200

(gdb) target remote /dev/ttyS0
Remote debugging using /dev/ttyS0
Ignoring packet error, continuing...

warning: unrecognized item "timeout" in "qSupported" response

Ignoring packet error, continuing...

Ignoring packet error, continuing...

Ignoring packet error, continuing...

Ignoring packet error, continuing...

Malformed response to offset query, timeout

> **I am not really getting what I am missing !**

P.S. I compiled the linux kernel 2.6.39.4 with KGDB options enabled. And I followed [these](http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/busybox-for-arm-on-qemu/) instructions to run kernel on qemu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you reference `/dev/ttyS0` on the host `gdb` will try to use the physical serial port present. You have to connect `qemu`'s emulated serial port to `gdb` instead.
Reading the `qemu` manual, apparently you can redirect the emulated port to tcp networking, by adding something like: `-serial tcp::1234,server` to the `qemu` command line. In `gdb` you can then connect using `target remote :1234`.

Comment: Okay thanks. But is it not possible to redirect my qemu serial port to my host's ttyS0 so that I could use /dev/ttyS0 from my gdb.

Comment: I don't understand: what would be the added value of using `/dev/ttyS0`?

Comment: You would only want to redirect QEMU to the host's /dev/ttyS0 if you wanted to use an actual cable to connect to a different physical machine running the debugger.  If you just want to debug from the same machine, you use local virtual method like TCP on the loopback interface or a unix domain socket.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real reason to use kgdb when your running within Qemu. You can simply specify something like "-gdb tcp::8888" on the Qemu command line and activate the GDB stub. You can then connect to the stub with an ARM aware GDB:

```
 target remote:8888
```

And debug away. You may find the following [gdb helper scripts useful](http://git.kiszka.org/?p=linux-2.6.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/queues/gdb-scripts)

Comment: Yes I know! But I want to emulate it as a remote machine so that I would get some hands on before I try on actual target machine. And is it possible to redirect my emulated serial port `/dev/ttyAMA0` to host's serial port `/dev/ttyS0` ?

Comment: @GeekFactory: sure, you can redirect the serial port. For example "-serial telnet:127.0.0.1:4444" will redirect it to a tcp socket.